# Given n line segments and a circular sector, find the leftmost and the rightmost segments

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

Suppose we are given an array of `n` 2D line segments as `[l_1, l_2,...,l_n]`, where `l_k = (s_k, e_k)` for each `k=1,2,...,n`, and a circular sector centered at the point `c`, determined by the triplet `(a_left, a_right, r)`, where `0 <= a_left, a_right <= 2pi, r >= 0`.

We want to either find the leftmost and the rightmost segments `l_left, l_right`, or determine that no such segments exists. The leftmost segment is that line segment which either intersects the radius originating from `c` at angle `a_left`, or alternatively that line segment which intersects the radius originating from `c` at the greatest rotation angle measured from the positive x-axis. Similarly, the rightmost segment is that line segment which is either intersected by the radius (originating from `c`) at angle `a_right`, or that segment which has the lowest rotation angle measured from the positive x-axis.

Note: Here we want a line segment `(s_k, e_k)` to be oriented such that the point `c` is to the right of the colinear line through `s_k` to `e_k`.

We can assume that an efficient method exists for determining the orientation of a line segment `(s_k, e_k)`, and if necessary we can re-order the points so that the they are oriented as we want.

**Picture**: [Example situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGzbK.png), where  points `A, B, C` determine the circular sector.

So far my attempt was to form an array of tuples `arr = [<first, second>_1, <first, second>_2,...,<first, second>_n]`, where `first` is the rotation angle of the leftmost point of a given line segment, and `second` is the index of the said segment in the original array. Then I could simply sort the tuples in an ascending order by the rotation angle, and determine by a linear search whether any segment `l_k` indicated by the kth pair in the array intersects the ray originating from `c`.

**Struggle**: To my understanding, my current problem is the discontinuity of the rotation angle I get from my API. Specifically, consider the case represented [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CIwX.png). Clearly the segment `(D, E)` has the greatest rotation angle of the segments, when double angles are allowed, but the API I have available gives `D` and `E` angles such that `a_D < a_E`. I tried to fixes this issue by first checking whether the rotation angle of the beginning vertex is less than that of the end vertex:`a_s_k < a_e_k` of a given segment `(s_k, e_k)`. But this did not solve the problem. Any pointers on what I should do?

Comment: Your description and your example do not match. In particular, you say that segment $I_k$ extends from $p_{k-1}$ to $p_k$. In particular, that means that $I_{k+1}$ extends from $p_k$ to $p_{k+1}$. Do you see it? These two segments share $p_k$ as an endpoint. Thus the segments you describe is a continuous polygonal curve. But your example shows disjoint segments. Which is it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, true! My bad. The segments do not need to be connected, so the the problem is described by the linked pictures.

Comment: Can you tell us which ones are the leftmost and the rightmost segments in the provided example? This is just to make sure whether I correctly understood your question.

Comment: @YNK In the first example the leftmost and rightmost segments are $(F, G)$ and $(L, M)$, respectively, while in the second example they are $(D, E)$ and $(H, I)$ (respectively).

Comment: There are a couple more questions I have. What conditions must a segment meet to qualify for consideration. Your examples show at least one endpoint in the sector, but your description only talks about angles, not whether the segment reaches inside the circle. Do you accept segments that begin and end outside the sector, but intersect it in their middle? Does it have to be inside the circle, or is only being within the angle of concern?

Comment: Also, can the sector have an angle of more than $\pi$? In particular, can the sector be wide enough that a segment could begin and end inside the sector, but in the middle pass outside?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Great questions! Any segment whose start or end point resides in the circular sector is considered for the leftmost/rightmost segment. Thus sector can have, for example, an angle greater than $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Here we want a line segment $(s_k, e_k)$ to be oriented such that the point $c$ is to the right of the colinear line through $s_k$ to $e_k$.

(BTW, "colinear line" is redundant.) This is a key property. As long as you choose $s_k$ and $e_k$ this way (so $(s_{ky}-c_y)(e_{kx}-c_x) \ge (s_{kx}-c_x)(e_{ky}-c_y)$), the problem has a simple solution. If travelling from $s_k$ to $e_k$ has the circle center on your right, then you are travelling clockwise, and the angle should be decreasing. That is, the argument for $e_k$ should always be less than or equal to the argument for $s_k$.

If this isn't true, there are two ways we can correct it: either add $2\pi$ to the argument of $s_k$ or subtract $2\pi$ from the argument of $e_k$. Which technique makes sense depends on whether we are looking for the rightmost or leftmost segment. And just to be clear, I assume that these mean:

- "Rightmost segment" is, among all segments with at least one end in the sector, the one with the most clockwise argument of all ends (include one outside the sector, provided the other end is in).
- "Leftmost segment" is, among all segments with at least one end in the sector, the one with the most counter-clockwise argument of all ends (include one outside the sector, provided the other end is in).

Note that if the sector happens to open downward (instead of upward as in your examples), the "Rightmost segment" will be on the left and the "Leftmost segment" will be on the right (this is why "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise" are the better terminology for rotational phenomena).

Initialize variables

```
MinIndex = -1
MaxIndex = -1
MinAngle = 13   # > 4 * pi
MaxAngle = -7   # < -2 * pi
```

Pass through your segments, skipping over any segment without at least one endpoint in the sector. For the rest,

- If $\arg s_k \ge \arg e_k$, then

  - if $\arg s_k >\text{ MaxAngle}$, then $\text{MaxAngle } = \arg s_k, \text{ MaxIndex } = k$.
  - if $\arg e_k <\text{ MinAngle}$, then $\text{MinAngle } = \arg e_k, \text{ MinIndex } = k$.
- If $\arg s_k < \arg e_k$, then

  - if $\arg s_k + 2\pi >\text{ MaxAngle}$, then $\text{MaxAngle } = \arg s_k + 2\pi, \text{ MaxIndex } = k$.
  - if $\arg e_k - 2\pi <\text{ MinAngle}$, then $\text{MinAngle } = \arg e_k - 2\pi, \text{ MinIndex } = k$.

When you are finished, MinIndex will point to the Leftmost segment and MaxIndex will point to the Rightmost.

Comment: Note that I am assuming your base argument range is $0$ to $2\pi$. If it is $-\pi$ to $\pi$, then MinAngle should be initialized to $10\ (> 3\pi)$ and MaxAngle should be initialized to $-10\ ( < -3\pi)$. The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{red}{\bf\text{This is not an answer}}$. What I am trying to do here is to understand your definition of the two technical terms, $\bf\text{leftmost segment }$ and $\bf\text{ rightmost segment }$. Please inspect the two figures given below carefully and tell us,

$\qquad 1.\space \text{whether } \color{red}{RS}\space \text{ is the rightmost segment of all segments shown in the } \mathrm{Fig.\space 1}\quad \bf{AND}$

$\qquad 2.\space \text{whether } \color{red}{PQ}\space \text{ is the rightmost segment of all segments shown in the } \mathrm{Fig.\space 2}.$

[image: Example1and2]

Comment: They've already answered your questions (which were also mine) in the last comment. "Any segment whose start or end point resides in the circular sector is considered for the leftmost/rightmost segment." Since neither $R$ nor $S$ are in the sector, $\overline{RS}$ is not included. Since $Q$ is in the sector, $\overline{PQ}$ is included. And as $Q$ is clockwise of all other points, it is the "rightmost" segment.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up question! In the first figure the segment $(R, S)$ is not the rightmost segment because its end vertices do not lie on the circular sector. Assuming the point $Q$ is right of the line passing through points $A$ and $M$, yes, the segment $(P, Q)$ is the rightmost segment in the figure 2.